# What Mesa and X.ORG version will Ubuntu 11.10 use

Tags: xorg, 11.10, mesa

With only 2 months left, what version of Mesa and X.org will Ubuntu 11.10 use. I ask this because of the changes to Intel graphic cards in the latest ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Target Versions for the 11.10 Oneric Release
---------------------------
   kernel:              3.0.0
   libdrm:              TBD (Probably 2.6.26)
   mesa:                7.11 (Plus updates)
   x-server:            1.10
   xorg:                7.6
   drivers:             TBD (Latest releases by Aug 18)
   gnome libs:          3.2 (GTK3)
```

Thanks goes out to Bryce Harrington for sending this to the ubuntu-devel mailing list:
source: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-June/033414.html

Comment: That is one good find in the mailing list.